# Heroku не может установить библиотеку requests

Tags: python, requests, heroku

Сделал бота на питоне, который делает запрос на сторонний сайт с помощью библиотеки requests, локально все работает, а при деплое на heroku, когда делаю `git push heroku master` , возникает следующая ошибка:

```
....
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement time (from versions: none)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for time
....
```

Почему может возникать эта ошибка, и как ее исправить?
(Если что, в файле requirements.txt я указал эту библиотеку)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно не корректно устанавливаете зависимости, проверьте, что устанавливаете зависимости вот так

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Одну минуту, я не понимаю, при чем тут pip3 install, если все библиотеки я просто указываю в текстовом файле requirements.txt

Comment: @fafa куда уж куда, но на heroku я не деплоил, поэтому предположил, что вы руками писали скрипт установки зависимостей, если heroku это делает автоматом, то попробуйте просто убрать версию модуля ==<version number> requests в requirements.txt

Comment: а ее там и так не было)))

Comment: @fafa Если не было то обязательно добавьте.

Comment: а как это должно выглядеть?